# Is it possible to auto change a value after an experation date of a year in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a value in a row in my database that needs to change automatically from 1 to 0 after a year. Is this possible? If so, could you please redirect me an easy to understand link with an explanation how this is done or explain to me how this is done? I'm just beginning with this and know very little. Thank you.

Comment: You can set up a start date value and then run an update query one year from the start date with where condition: `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STARTDATE, CURDATE()) > 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Mysql EVENT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Example

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a scheduler for this that can be run at the end of year..

And in the scheduler you can update your desired rows..

Comment: The change of the value is depending on the register date of a user. So the change is user specific.

Comment: yes you can add that condition in the query..
for example: update those rows only WHERE user date has completed 1 year only..

And you can also use cron job by creating a script..